# Initializer list of std::pair<vector<int>, double>

Tags: c++

Hi I am working through some C++ issues and I'm not familiar with the language.

I am trying to initialize a std::pair, double> with this syntax:

```
 std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> output = { {}, 0.0f };
```

gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 generates this error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>’ to ‘std::initializer_list<int>
```

The same error happens if I use this syntax:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> output{{}, 0.0f };
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What compiler do you use? What version of C++ do you use? This is a valid initiazation on gcc 9.2 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EZUjwP

Comment: gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The compiler (gcc 5.4) is giving this warning: [x86-64 gcc 5.4 #1] warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 . Extended initializers came in C++11, so you need to compile it with that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an extended initializer list ([std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)) which is available since C++11.

For the gcc 5.4.0 compiler, you need to compile it with C++11 flag:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SHzREE